# Does anybody know of a Wordpress plugin that produces a PDF locally?

Tags: wordpress, pdf

The function of the plugin is to print the page contents as a PDF.

I can find a bunch that connect to an external service in a popup to generate the PDF, but I can't seem to find one that produces the PDF on the server where the PDF needs to be generated.

The reason I don't want to use these external services is because of branding, and because most of them have advertising. If it wasn't for this, I wouldn't mind using these plugins either.

I'm OK with paying money if the plugin is good enough.

P.S. On an unrelated note, Wordpress' plugin search sucks :( I can't filter by version number, compatibility, etc.

Comment: The PDF will contain the contents of that page, so an article, for example.

Comment: Had the same problem today. Made my research and most plugins will only take the_content() and the_title() to put it in the PDF. My problem was dealt with by only doing a print css. Is it really that crucial to save the PDF? End of the line is that there's not a lot of plugins doing it. Even less doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this http://www.investintech.com/resources/blog/archives/167-top-10-handy-wordpress-pdf-plugins.html

Should help you find what you need.

I already tried Print Friendly, and I think it could work in your situation.

Comment: I've actually looked at all the plugins on that list already. Print Friendly is nice, but it shows advertising, and even without the advertising, it's layout is too different from the rest of my site.

Comment: Well seems like you confirm my tought... there's no homemade plugin that converts efficiently WP pages to PDFs. So the only option I see for you is to create that plugin yourself. If only there would be a code that takes your code as if you were printing the page and exports that to a PDF. Would be just perfect.

Comment: Yes, you're right - by the way, to clarify, I don't have a problem with converting the whole article. The problem is that the Print Friendly and other plugins display their own layout in the popup, which is completely different from my site's layout.

Comment: I'm on the same page as you on that part; Favorited, just to see if someone will come up with something.